# Empty map guard not working

Tags: elixir

Why is this guard not working?

```
def method(stuff, %{}), do: stuff
```

and I have to check the map size to make it work?

```
def method(stuff, data) when map_size(data) == 0, do: stuff
```

Shouldnt the first guard match an empty map?

Comment: I would also recommend that you use is_map along with map_size to prevent map_size from throwing the BadMapError.

Comment: @lapinkoira A guard clause starts with the `when` keyword and is followed by a boolean expression: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/guards.html . As such, you may want to revise the terminology employed in your question as the first code example provided by you does not contain a guard clause.

Comment: @Raghu functions in guard expressions never throw errors to the user. If there is an error, the guard silently evaluates to false and the clause is skipped. `map_size(map) == 0` is therefore correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A map pattern matches even if the value contains any keys not present in the pattern. The extra keys are silently ignored. Checking `map_size(map) == 0` is the right way to check if the argument is an empty map.